# Use jq to update property of object that contains other property with specific value

Tags: bash, configuration, json, jq

Using jq, is it possible to update property value of an object that contains a specific value in some other property?

In the example below I'd like to set the value of the "value" property of all objects that have "keyname" = "foo".

The example .json file looks like this:

```
"root" : {
  "instances": [
    {
      "name": "1",
      "configs": [
        {
          "keyname": "foo",
          "value": "" // <- update/set this
        },
        {
          "keyname": "barrr",
          "value": "barrrr"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "configs": [
        {
          "keyname": "foo",
          "value": "" // <- update/set this
        },
        {
          "keyname": "buzzz",
          "value": "buzzz"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this but in vain, I get an error about array not being a string:

```
jq '(.root.instances.configs[] | select(.keyname==foo)).value = foo'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your JSON document is well formed, which the example that you show is not as it contains multiple issues:

```bsh
$ cat file
{
  "root": {
    "instances": [
      {
        "name": "1",
        "configs": [
          {
            "keyname": "foo",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "keyname": "barrr",
            "value": "barrrr"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "2",
        "configs": [
          {
            "keyname": "foo",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "keyname": "buzzz",
            "value": "buzzz"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```bsh
$ jq '( .root.instances[].configs[] | select(.keyname == "foo") ).value |= "foo"' file
{
  "root": {
    "instances": [
      {
        "name": "1",
        "configs": [
          {
            "keyname": "foo",
            "value": "foo"
          },
          {
            "keyname": "barrr",
            "value": "barrrr"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "2",
        "configs": [
          {
            "keyname": "foo",
            "value": "foo"
          },
          {
            "keyname": "buzzz",
            "value": "buzzz"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This `jq` expression updates the value of the `.value` key to the string `foo`.  The key that is updated is selected from one of the entries in `.root.instances[].configs[]`.  Note that  `.root.instances` is an array and that each `.configs` entry in each of its elements is also an array.  The `select()` statement tests the `.keyname` key with the string `foo`.

Making the query key and new value variable is done as follows:

```bsh
jq  --arg querykey 'foo' \
    --arg newval 'The train said "choo choo"' \
    '( .root.instances[].configs[] | select(.keyname == $querykey) ).value |= $newval' file
```

This creates two internal `jq` variables called `$querykey` and `$newval`.  Their values will be properly encoded, so that e.g. `$newval` can contain double quotes, as shown above.